# How to get URL of media filtered by tag

Tags: python, tags, instagram

I am trying to filter instagram photos by tags.
I've tried with this code:

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

access_token = "MY_ACCESS_TOKEN"
api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)
filtered_media = api.tag_recent_media(count=2, max_id=1, tag_name="dog")
for media in filtered_media:
   print media
```

and the output is:

[Media: 865816832933050000_607020460, Media: 865816825652168229_1424270880]
[removed url]

where the link leads to a huge amount of info that I don't understand.
So I tried another code to get only the urls of the filtered photo. I changed only the last print instruction:

```
   print media.images['standard_resolution'].url
```

and i get:

```
print media.images['standard_resolution'].url
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'images'
```

Why it turns out to be wrong? when I use this instruction to print recent popular photos it works.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet:

```
for media in filtered_media[0]:
    print media.images['standard_resolution'].url
```

Api returns list with media objects and string with requested url.

By the way remove url from your output in question, because it contains access token)

Comment: Thank you Alex for noticing that! I removed it.
I'm going to try this and let you know if it works